# Requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead.learner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, carrierwave, rmagick

I'm currently trying to deploy to Heroku and after a few tries, I'm getting an error >> `[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead`.

I'm a newbie to this, so I need someone to explain what I'm doing wrong and what I need to change.

Thanks in advance!

In my Gemfile, this is the only line that has anything to do with rmagick

`gem 'rmagick'`

And in my ImageUploader file, I have this line

`include CarrierWave::RMagick`

That's about it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because your CarrierWave version is locked to a version your Gemfile. The issue was fixed with [CarrierWave Backport](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1788)

What happens when you remove the version of CarrierWave and delete your `Gemfile.lock` then run `bunle install`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's no version next to my Carrierwave. In my Gemfile, it is written like `gem 'carrierwave'`. Should i still be looking to delete my Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I think my issue is with heroku, as i have no problems in development. But i tried to deploy to heroku and i got this error!

Comment: Yes, I think you should delete your Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install` again.

Comment: You should not delete the _Gemfile.lock_ but try `bundle update carrierwave` to update only what is really needed. BTW: This fixed it for me.